# Hide records on click in the front end temporarily - rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I want to hide the respective records when **Hide** link is been clicked.

Please refer the screen-shot for better understanding as shown below;

[image: screenshot.png]

Before the link is clicked, hidden attribute is false as shown in the terminal as below;

[image: Screenshot1.png]

After the link is clicked, it grabs the respective id and calls the **hide** method on the controller which is as shown below;

[image: Screenshot2.png]

The problem is that it doesn't either hide that respective row or escape those values from the balance calculation and gets redirected to xvaziris_url.

I tried again and again in order to sort out this issue but unfortunately unable to get the desired result.

xvaziris_controller.rb

```
def index
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.find_by hidden: false
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html 
        end 
    end

def hide
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
        @xvaziri.hidden = true
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully hidden.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :xvaziris do
        member do
            get :hide
        end
    end
```

_xvaziri.html.erb

```
<td class="col-1"><%= link_to "Hide", controller: "xvaziris", action: "hide", id: xvaziri, method: :get %></td>
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post text as text whenever possible rather than as images.  Images have a great many shortcomings compared to plain text.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't save the result of your action. This code `@xvaziri.hidden = true` just sets the `hidden` attribute into `true`. You need to save the `@xvaziri`.

Try this solution.

```
def hide
  @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
  @xvaziri.update_attribute(:hidden, true)
  flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully hidden.'
  redirect_to xvaziris_url    
end
```

**UPDATE**

I just made a clone of your application and find out the issue.

First of all `find_by` returns only first result as describet [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

And second you are always getting xvaziris instances which has been found by your search method not by `find_by`

So, let's go through you controller's index action

```
def index
    @xvaziris = Xvaziri.find_by hidden: false
    # find first not hidden xvaziri and
    # store in into @xvaziris variable

    @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search])
    # find xvaziris according to search performed
    # and store it into @xvaziris variable 
    # so, at this place you always have xvaziris 
    #that has been found but they may be hidden.

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html 
    end 
end
```

Here are some suggestions

First of all implement some methods in `Xvaziri model`

```
class Xvaziri < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :visible, -> { where(hidden: false) }
  # returns only visible xvaziri's

  def hide
    update_attribute(:hidden, true)
  end

  def show
    update_attribute(:hidden, false)
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
def index
  @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search]).visible

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html 
  end 
end

def hide
  @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
  @xvaziri.hide
  flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully hidden.'
  redirect_to xvaziris_url    
end
```

*Show hidden xvaziri*

```
# app/models/xvaziri.rb
scope :hidden, -> { where(hidden: true) }

# app/controllers/xvaziris_controller.rb
def hidden
  @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search]).hidden
end

def unhide
  xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
  xvaziri.show
  flash[:notice] = "Xvaziri is now visible."
  redirect_to hidden_url
end

#app/views/xvaziris/hidden.html.erb

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Xvaziris</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% if @xvaziris.any? %>
      <% @xvaziris.each do |xvaziri| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= xvaziri.id %></td>
          <td><%= xvaziri.description %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'unhide', unhide_xvaziri_path(xvaziri), method: :put %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

# config/routes.rb
resources :xvaziris do 
  member do 
    get :hide
    get :unhide 
  end
end
get "hidden" => "xvaziris#hidden"
```

But it's not good to use `:get` methods to modify the model. Consider yo use `:put` method instead.

In my view example link uses `:put` method

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried but it is not working for me.What's next? As it is not taking hidden attribute as true...

Comment: Pretty weird. Could you please pass a log messages you are seeing with `update_attribute`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.That's for sure.

Comment: Started GET "/xvaziris/125/hide?method=get" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-01 10:49:25 +0400
Processing by XvazirisController#hide as HTML
  Parameters: {"method"=>"get", "id"=>"125"}
  Xvaziri Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "xvaziris".* FROM "xvaziris" WHERE "xvaziris"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["i
d", 125]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/xvaziris

Comment: As I can see transaction has been made. Let's discuss that in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/118774/hide-records-on-click-in-the-front-end-temporarily-rails-4-2?tab=general

Comment: I'm really sorry for that delay. I just updated the answer and it works for me.

Comment: Excellent! It worked but how to show up the hidden records back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.At present I can hide rows from index page and how do I access hidden rows that is how about routing?

Comment: For hide I have,                                                                                   root 'xvaziris#index'

    resources :xvaziris do
        member do
            get :hide
        end
    end                                                                                                       but how about unhide?

Comment: Thanks. I my index page I have the hide links when I execute the link it is hidden but the confusion is where do I find the unhide link in order to get back that hidden row to appear in my root_path.

Comment: Consider `hidden` action in the controller. It displays hidden xvaziris

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120197/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-retgoat).